# Upload data using selling-partner-api in Amazon using PHP

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-product-api

I have successfully encrypted the required parameters, but I am posting the data to this URL

https://tortuga-prod-na.s3-external-1.amazonaws.com/%2FNinetyDays/amzn1.tortuga.3.xxxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxxxxx.xxxxx

Drops me this error AuthorizationHeaderMalformedThe authorization header is malformed; incorrect service "execute-api". This endpoint belongs to "s3".9DD75A286E7422B6rxCxNZ3veB/3ZJ1qrtvleA0JaHTPqprLYe3I5mM/LYLLEVPL6iKGv0irGmV1O9SS4AcmPsM/8/I=

```
$headers = [
    'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8',
    'X-Amz-Content-Sha256: UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD',
    'X-Amz-Date: 20210105T095435Z',
    'Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential={ access-key-when-create-IAM }/20210105/us-east-1/execute-api/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-access-token;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date, Signature={generated through auth process}',
];
```

I have lost no idea what's wrong. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Change service from 'execute-api' to 's3'